# React vertical range slider always resets to default ignoring new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rangeslider

I'm using a vertical range slider to control volume in a React component.

Everything works as expected in Chrome, but in Firefox, no matter what value you change it to it always reverts to the default value - completely ignoring the new state.

The function is actually working in Firefox (the volume of the audio track is altered as expected while the slider is being moved) but as soon as I `mouseup` it switches back to the default value.

Here is the full Volume component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Volume extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  slider = null;
  state = {
    volume: 100
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.slider = document.getElementById('volume');
    this.slider.addEventListener('mouseup', this.hideSlider, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
    this.slider.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.hideSlider, false);
  }

  hideSlider = () => {
    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.slider.style.display = 'none';
    }
  };

  onChange = e => {
    let newState = { volume: e.target.value };
    let value = e.target.value / 100;
    this.setState(newState, function() {
      this.props.setVolume(value);
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.volume);
    return (
      <div id="volume">
        <input
          type="range"
          orient="vertical"
          min="1"
          max="100"
          step="1"
          value={this.state.volume}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Volume.propTypes = {
  setVolume: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Volume;
```

I've even set up the setState callback function to avoid a potential race condition but still no love...

Could it be to do with the fact that I am hiding the slider (with CSS) on `mouseout`? Chrome doesn't have a problem with this at all?

Just to clarify - it's the `volume` **state** that is being reset to the default value on `mouseout` on Firefox, in turn setting the range slider to the default value again.

Comment: Ahh I think I've seen the issue. I'm mounting the component every time I open the volume slider with it's parent component. So I should be setting the volume state in the parent and not this one, as every time it's mounted it's setting the default state again. Why would this work in Chrome though?

Comment: Update : Nope. I tried controlling the volume state from the parent, same issue. Firefox is just being a pain in the arse!

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error it turns out that it is the CSS rule that is making the slider default to it's original value on Firefox.

The slider is hidden by default, an icon is clicked to (unhide) display it, once the value has been changed and you `mouseup` on the range slider the following css rule is called to hide it :

```
this.slider.style.display = 'none';
```

This instantly restores the default value in Firefox - sending that to the state, but as mentioned in the original question - this works perfectly fine in Chrome. So Firefox doesn't like the fact that the element is being hidden, very strange behaviour, never come across this one before.

Anyway the solution is to add a `setTimeout` on the CSS rule :

```
hideSlider = () => {
   setTimeout(this.doit, 300);
};

doit = () => {
   this.slider.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Annoying quirk to have to overcome just for Firefox but at least it works.